# Refresh page periodically using jquery, ajax and django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to create notifications for my django app where I have to display changes in database in a div in my template. I want ajax to hit my database periodically and if there are any changes then they should be displayed in that div.
I want my data to come from 3 different models and any change in either of them should be notified in my template's div.

How can I do that?

Template:

```
 <div class="notification">
        {% for like in likes_notify %}
        {% if like.item.reward != None %}
            <div class="like_newsfeed">
                <a href="/employee/{{ emp_code }}/social-info/single-news-feed/{{ like.item.reward.pk }}/show/"> &nbsp;{{ like.user.get_full_name }} liked your post : {{ like.item.reward }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
            </div>
           {% else %}
            <div class="like_news_post">{{ like.item.comment.pk }}
                <a href="/employee/{{ emp_code }}/social-info/single-news-feed/{{ like.item.comment.pk }}/show/">&nbsp;{{ like.user.get_full_name }} liked your comment "{{ like.item.comment }}".&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
<br><hr>
    {% for comment in comments_notify %}
        {% if comment.item.reward != None %}
            <div class="comment_newsfeed">
                <a href="/employee/{{ emp_code }}/social-info/single-news-feed/{{ comment.item.reward.pk }}/show/"> &nbsp;{{ comment.user.get_full_name }} commented on your post : {{ comment.item.reward }} with "{{ comment }}".&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
            </div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="comment_news_post">{{ comment }}
                <a href="/employee/{{ emp_code }}/social-info/single-news-feed/{{ comment.item.reward.pk }}/show/"> &nbsp;{{ comment.user.get_full_name }} commented on your post "{{ comment }}".&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
            </div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
<br><hr>
    {% for reward in rewards_notify %}
        <div class="reward_newsfeed">
            <a href="/employee/{{ emp_code }}/social-info/single-news-feed/{{ reward.pk }}/show/">&nbsp;{{reward.role_history.organisation_role.user.get_full_name }} got a reward :  {{ reward }}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

JS:

```
  function worker(){
    var url =  '/employee/'+get_emp_code()+'/home/dashboard/';
//    $(".notification").load(url + ' .notification',data, function () { setTimeout(worker, 5000);  });
    $.ajax({
        type:'get',
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
//      $('.notification').load(url + " .notification", data);
//      $('.notification').load(url + " .notification").html(data);
      $('.notification').html(data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      // Schedule the next request when the current one's complete
      setTimeout(worker, 3000);
    }
  });
}
$(document).ready(function(){
setTimeout(worker, 5000);
    });
```

I have tried writing this js but this loads my entire page twice and not the div. I have actually extended a base template into this template so it loads the entire base template's data also in my div.

View:

```
def get_context(request,*args,**kwargs):
    context = {}
    likes = Like.objects.exclude(user = request.user).order_by('-date_edited')[:2]
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(user = request.user).order_by('-last_updated')[:2]
    rewards = Reward.objects.filter(role_history__organisation_role__organisation=request.user.organisation_user.organisation, approved=True).order_by('-last_updated')[:2]
    #notification = chain(likes,comments,rewards)

    context.update({'likes_notify':likes,'comments_notify':comments,
                    'rewards_notify':rewards})
```

This is the portion in my view for which i want to make my notifications for.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Post your existing code and describe specific problems you have with your approach and people will help you with it.

Comment: Please check my edited code and help if possible. Right now I am just displaying the user's name. That I will modify once I get to display my notifications properly in my template.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the answer to my question. I just modified my js with this code:

JS:

```
success: function(data) {
var dtr = $('.notification',data);
$('.notification').html(dtr);
}
```