# Django template data update using ajax

Tags: django, ajax, django-templates

I am trying to update my data periodically (10 seconds) on a Django template using ajax scripts. I am relatively new in front-end development.

Using other articles, I am able to do so. But everytime page refreshes, multiple threads for page refreshing are created and update requests are doubled every 10 secods.

**Following is my django template snippet:**

```
<body id="page-top">
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="table-info">
        <th style="text-align:center">Parameter</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">A</th>
        <th style="text-align:center">B</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      {% for para, details in manualData.items %}
      <tr>
         <th style="text-align:center" scope="row">{{ details.1.name }}</th>
           {% for key, entity in details.items %}
        <td style="text-align:center">
                <font color="white" size="4px">{{ entity.value }}</font>
            </td>
           {% endfor %}
          </tr>     
      {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
```

**I am using ajax script as follows:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function refresh() {
         var_ref =  $.ajax({
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#page-top').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
        $(function () {
            setInterval('refresh()', 10000);
        });
    </script>
```

Conclusively, all I need is:

> once the refreshing process is **called**, *new process* should **not** be
>   created, or else *past process to be aborted if new process is to be
>   defined*.

Kindly help me to attain the same.

Thanks in advance

Nakul

Comment: What does your view look like, and what do you have in "data" ?

Comment: Well, `id="page-top"` is the whole `body`... Perhaps you need to request from backend or  rewrite on frontend something more specific, e.g. global `div` inside body while keeping script outside of this div. Also you might prefer to start your timer on `$( document ).ready()`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Refresh page periodically using jquery, ajax and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906593/refresh-page-periodically-using-jquery-ajax-and-django)

Answer (score 0):

You need your ajax call to be synchronomous instead of async, this way you will block the thread until you get the data you require

Can be done by adding the [corresponding attribute on the ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478295/what-does-async-false-do-in-jquery-ajax)

When within the industry you would normally use the template system to load something like react, angular or vue which constantly update the DOM without having to make endless polling

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the answer at post: [Refresh page periodically using jquery, ajax and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22906593/refresh-page-periodically-using-jquery-ajax-and-django).

Also, Thank you @Mr-Programs for your suggestion regarding async attribute.

I have got a suitable answer for my query and updated the javascript as follows.

```html
<script>
         function worker(){
         var url =  'yoururl';
         $.ajax({
          type:'get',
          url: url,
          async: false,
          success: function(data) {
          var dtr = $('.page-top',data); 
          # not necessarily body div, can use any section required to be updated
          $('.page-top').html(dtr);
                complete: function() {
                setTimeout(worker, 10000);
               }
          });
         }
         $(document).ready(function(){
         setTimeout(worker, 10000);
         });

         };
        </script>
```